# Can't make ESlint work on VSC, keep having 'unexpected error...in Json...'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I am learning JS and I am trying to install ESlint but I keep having the same error.

Just trying to install ESlint on VSC, but never got it working. I have uninstalled and reinstalled eslint, cache clean, installed and removed several packages without success, it comes back with the same error.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "11_06",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
"ESLint: Unexpected token n in JSON at position 173. Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details."
```

How/where/which file can I look at line 173 for the issue?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I found the source of the problem, despite installing eslint several times properly using the recommended methods by npm or auto install, globally and locally, then cleaning cache and trying it again and again, I eventually found a problem with the way eslint was installing on my VSC, I don't know why but it was not creating the eslintrc.json file with the basic info. Once I created it manually eslint started working. Still don't know what I have done wrong initially. Good luck.